# Removing Identity_Insert from a Temp Table that is Generated Dynamically

Tags: sql-server, identity, audit

I've got a Stored Procedure that I want to audit all the changes it makes to many tables.  This bit of code repeated down the SP but with different table names.  Once that piece of script is finish I then copy the contents of the temp table to my audit table which works well.

I have a problem with one table which bring back this message: An explicit value for the identity column in table '#MyTempTable' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

I'm lazy, I don't want to specify all the column names.  Is there a way to remove the identity from the temp table after I created it?

```html
--Create Temp Audit Table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable') IS NOT NULL drop table #MyTempTable; 
select top 0 * into #MyTempTable from TabletoAudit


--Do changes and record into TempTable
UPDATE TabletoAudit
SET 
 series_nm = @newseries,
 UPDATED_DT = GetDate()

OUTPUT deleted.* INTO #MyTempTable

WHERE 
 mach_type_cd = @mtype
 AND 
 brand_id = @brand
 AND 
 series_nm = @oldseries


--Copy Contents from Temp table to Audit Table
```

Answer (score 3):

If the identity column is the first column (usually it is) then you can also:

assuming data type INT, column name originalid

```
SELECT top 0 CONVERT(INT,0)myid,* into #MyTempTable from TabletoAudit
ALTER TABLE #MyTempTable DROP COLUMN originalid
EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_rename N'#MyTempTable.myid', N'originalid', N'COLUMN'
```

Comment: You can skip the ALTER and EXEC lines if you include the column names instead of using *.

Comment: Yes i could but i need to maintain fields in the future that way, or build sql dynamically,both require extra effort.

Comment: Sure, I was just adding that as an option for people looking at this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I spent over a day researching into this but now finally found a solution.  Simply when I create it, create it without the Identity in the first place. I did this by creating a dynamic script to create a temp table based on another and don't add identity.

```html
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##MyTempTable') IS NOT NULL drop table ##INSERTED7; 
SET NOCOUNT ON;


DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @CreateSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM TabletoAudit;';
SELECT @CreateSQL = 'CREATE TABLE ##MyTempTable(';
SELECT 
    @CreateSQL = @CreateSQL + CASE column_ordinal 
        WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE ',' END 
        + name + ' ' + system_type_name + CASE is_nullable 
        WHEN 0 THEN ' not null' ELSE '' END
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (@sql, NULL, 0) AS f
ORDER BY column_ordinal;
SELECT @CreateSQL = @CreateSQL + ');';


EXEC sp_executesql @CreateSQL;
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

I also changed the Temp Table to a Global Temp Table for it to work.